# how do you calculate and return a total value in c#?

Tags: c#, methods

I'm, trying to add a method `Takings` which calculates and returns the total value of all the bookings for this show. If anyone could lead me in the right direction that would be great :)

```
 namespace GCUShows
 {
 public class Show
 {
    private string title;
    private Dictionary<int, Booking> bookings;

    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set { title = value; }
    }

    public Show(string title)
    {
        this.title = title;
        this.bookings = new Dictionary<int, Booking>();
    }

    public void AddBooking(int bookingID, Booking booking)
    {
        this.bookings.Add(bookingID, booking);
    }

    public void RemoveBooking(int bookingID, Booking booking)
    {
        this.bookings.Remove(bookingID);
    }
    public Takings
    {
    }
}


namespace GCUShows
{
public enum TicketType
{
    Adult,
    Child,
    Family
}

public class Booking : ITicket
{
    private const int LIMIT = 6;

    public Show show;
    private int bookingID;
    public List<ITicket> tickets;
    
    public int BookingID
    {
        get { return bookingID; }
        set { bookingID = value; }
    }
   
    public Booking(Show show)
    {
        this.BookingID = BookingIDSequence.Instance.NextID;
        this.show = show;
        show.AddBooking(this);
        this.tickets = new List<ITicket>();
    }

    public void AddTickets(int number, TicketType type, decimal fee)
    {
        if (type == TicketType.Adult)
        {
            for(int i =0; i < number; i++)
            {
                tickets.Add(new AdultTicket(show.Title, fee));
            }
        }
            else if (type == TicketType.Child)
            {
                for(int i=0; i< number; i++)
                {
                    tickets.Add(new ChildTicket(show.Title));
                 }
            }
        else if (type == TicketType.Family)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
            {
                tickets.Add(new FamilyTicket(show.Title, fee));
            }
         }
    }
   
    public string PrintTickets()
    {
        string ticketInfo = "Booking " + bookingID.ToString() + "\n";
        foreach (ITicket ticket in tickets)
        {
            ticketInfo += ticket.Print();
        }
        return ticketInfo;
    }

    public decimal TotalCost()
    {
        decimal totalCost;
        foreach (ITicket ticket in tickets)
        {
            totalCost += ticket.Fee;
        }
        return totalCost;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}: Total Cost={1:c}", bookingID, TotalCost());
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Can you add the definition of `Booking`?

Comment: It's impossible to answer your question because you left out important details. You also didn't include how you're attempting to calculate the total.

Comment: Why you need method here. You can use property `public int Takes{get{return bookings.Values.Sum(b => b.Val);}}`. however, where does bookings get assigned?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `Bookings` contains a property `int Val`, it could look like:

```
public int Takes()
{
    return bookings.Values.Sum(b => b.Val);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If Booking has a Cost property, you can do this:

```
var total = bookings.Sum(x => x.Value.Cost);
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to other Linq answer you can do the same thing with a `foreach`

```
public decimal Takings()
{
    decimal runningTotal = 0;
    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Booking> kvp in bookings) {
        runningTotal += kvp.Value.TotalCost();
    }
    return runningTotal;
}
```

which might look a little less "magic" if you are new to programming.

Answer (score 0):

this is my bookings class

namespace GCUShows
{
    public enum TicketType
    {
        Adult,
        Child,
        Family
    }

```
public class Booking : ITicket
{
    private const int LIMIT = 6;

    public Show show;
    private int bookingID;
    public List<ITicket> tickets;

    public int BookingID
    {
        get { return bookingID; }
        set { bookingID = value; }
    }

    public Booking(Show show)
    {
        this.BookingID = BookingIDSequence.Instance.NextID;
        this.show = show;
        show.AddBooking(this);
        this.tickets = new List<ITicket>();
    }

    public void AddTickets(int number, TicketType type, decimal fee)
    {
        if (type == TicketType.Adult)
        {
            for(int i =0; i < number; i++)
            {
                tickets.Add(new AdultTicket(show.Title, fee));
            }
        }
            else if (type == TicketType.Child)
            {
                for(int i=0; i< number; i++)
                {
                    tickets.Add(new ChildTicket(show.Title));
                 }
            }
        else if (type == TicketType.Family)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
            {
                tickets.Add(new FamilyTicket(show.Title, fee));
            }
         }
    }

    public string PrintTickets()
    {
        string ticketInfo = "Booking " + bookingID.ToString() + "\n";
        foreach (ITicket ticket in tickets)
        {
            ticketInfo += ticket.Print();
        }
        return ticketInfo;
    }

    public decimal TotalCost()
    {
        decimal totalCost;
        foreach (ITicket ticket in tickets)
        {
            totalCost += ticket.Fee;
        }
        return totalCost;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}: Total Cost={1:c}", bookingID, TotalCost());
    }

}
```

}

Comment: You can edit your original post to add the necesary code or whatever people asks you to include. Now, for the question: You already have the logic you're looking for in the `TotalCost` function of the `Booking` class. Just iterate over the `values` property of your dictionary.